# MariaDB SELECT query keeps stuck in one system but not in another

Tags: mariadb, performance-tuning, slow-log, mariadb-10.6

This is the reduced query showing problem:

```
 SELECT 
  t.*
FROM 
  transactions t 
  LEFT JOIN assignments a ON a.transaction_id = t.id 
  LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = a.user_id  
WHERE (
    u2.operational_type IS NULL
  );
```

In Production Server (Ubuntu 21.04; mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.13-MariaDB) is executing in 0.0179 seconds. Explain in production server returns:

```
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+------------------+-------+-------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref              | rows  | Extra                   |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+------------------+-------+-------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ALL    | NULL           | NULL           | NULL    | NULL             | 56542 |                         |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref    | transaction_id | transaction_id | 4       | dbname.t.id      | 1     |                         |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | u2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY        | 4       | dbname.a.user_id | 1     | Using where; Not exists |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+------------------+-------+-------------------------+
```

However in developing server (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS; mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.7-MariaDB) it gets stuck, In processlist it's state is sending data, it has been more than 30 minutes. Its EXPLAIN is as following:

```
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys  | key     | key_len | ref              | rows  | Extra                                           |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ALL    | NULL           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | 48735 |                                                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL    | transaction_id | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | 1     | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | u2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY | 4       | dbname.a.user_id | 1     | Using where; Not exists                         |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

What is the cause? How to troubleshoot?

EDIT: `SHOW TABLE STATUS` for Production Server.

```
+-----------------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
| Name                  | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows  | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options | Comment | Max_index_length | Temporary |
+-----------------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
| assignments           | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 50175 |             52 |     2637824 |               0 |      3178496 |   4194304 |          51273 | 2022-07-08 08:18:28 | 2022-08-29 12:40:28 | NULL       | utf8mb4_spanish_ci |     NULL |                |         |                0 | N         |
| transactions          | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 37315 |           1505 |    56180736 |               0 |      3719168 |   7340032 |          41549 | 2022-07-13 11:18:23 | 2022-09-03 15:34:44 | NULL       | utf8mb4_spanish_ci |     NULL |                |         |                0 | N         |
| users                 | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    |   243 |            741 |      180224 |               0 |        81920 |         0 |            267 | 2022-08-20 12:33:16 | 2022-09-08 11:12:24 | NULL       | utf8mb4_spanish_ci |     NULL |                |         |                0 | N
```

`SHOW TABLE STATUS` developing server:

```
+-----------------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
| Name                  | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows  | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options | Comment | Max_index_length | Temporary |
| assignments           | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    |     0 |              0 |       16384 |               0 |        32768 |   4194304 |          75369 | 2022-09-11 08:05:19 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_spanish_ci |     NULL |                |         |                0 | N         |
| transactions          | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 48735 |           1497 |    72974336 |               0 |      4767744 |   6291456 |          62236 | 2022-09-11 08:05:15 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_spanish_ci |     NULL |                |         |                0 | N         |
| users                 | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    |   275 |            714 |      196608 |               0 |        98304 |         0 |            296 | 2022-09-11 12:09:11 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_spanish_ci |     NULL |                |         |                0 | N         |
```

I don't understand why assigments table show 0 rows. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM assignments WHERE 1` returns 74061

Comment: `SHOW TABLE STATUS` for the 3 tables on each server.  (Need to see how big the tables are.)  Compare `SHOW CREATE TABLE` between servers.

Comment: *What is the cause?* Different tables statistic. Execute ANALYZE TABLE.

Comment: @RickJames added to question

Comment: @RickJames `SHOW CREATE TABLE` only differs in `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: @Akina How should I run `ANALYZE TABLE`? `ANALYZE TABLE assignments` for example doesn't return useful information https://imgur.com/a/2AxZgfd

Comment: Have you read this command description in the documention? Have you understood WHAT this command do?

Comment: @Akina Sorry I tought it was used to retrieve information. After running `ANALTYZE TABLE` the select command run immediately and succesfull. However I don't really understand why this command was needed, and if there is a risk that SELECT gets stuck again after switching server to production.

Comment: @NeDark - `ANALYZE TABLE` gathers some statistics that may (or may not) help in future queries.  Running it _might_ have fixed the mysterious "0". Did you run the `SHOW TABLE STATUS` again?  (I have never seen the "0" with a big count(*)!)

Comment: I see that one use BNL, which is usually very efficient.  Could you get an "optimizer trace" for each server.

Comment: @RickJames Yes now it has 72364

Comment: @RickJames What is an optimizer trace?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-internals-documentation-optimizer-trace/